# Slack - add all members when creating channel. Number of users limit?

Tags: slack

I'm admin on two Slack workspaces. When creating a channel on the first (3 members), it looks like this (after choosing name and description):

[image]

When I create a channel in the second workspace (14 members), it looks like this (after choosing name and description):

[image]

Slack claims this "Add all members" feature only disappears when the workspace has 150 users.

I can't find discrepancies in the settings. Any suggestions why this is the case? Thanks

Comment: For context, Slack mentions the limit of 150 people on [this page](https://slack.com/intl/en-in/help/articles/115004846068-Slack-updates-and-changes#2020).